# Does WebPack loader addDependency add a file to the bundle?

Tags: webpack, webpack-loader

When using the WebPack Loader API, does `this.addDependency` also add the file to the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

No, it only add this file as a dependency of the file that is loaded via the loader. That means that each change in the dependent file, webpack will re-build the module that the dependency was added to.

This is like a "watch" on the dependent file.

Comment: When you say "module", do you mean the file that was passed into the loader? Or something else (e.g every file that the loader loads or something similar).

Comment: Module is a webpack terminology, it is the file that passed to the loader.